# Rails 2 default routes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm working in updating an application from ruby 2.3.xx to 3.2 and I'm doing one step each time.

The application uses the default routes from rais 2.3.xx as described bellow:

```
# Install the default route as the lowest priority.
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action.:format'
map.connect ':controller.:format'
```

Of course, you don't want to have this kind of route on your Rails 3 application, but because of the update process, I want to do small steps. So first step is make things work with these routes and afterwards eliminate it.

So, the question: How to write this routes in rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Rails 3 `config/routes.rb`

```
# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment, but right you are on a 15 minute time limit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer